# What is the syntax for griddb to create analytics query like

Tags: griddb

I have created database on griddb containerize,  in which departments and salaries are stored. I want to implement one case to categorize salaries like low/high. In SQL it is easy to implement but how the syntax looks like in gridbdb?

```
select distinct month, dept_id, 
case when dep_avg>compare_avg then "higher"
when dep_avg= compare_avg then "same"
else "lower"
end as category
from salaries
```

I have to work on analytics queries using griddb, what is the best possible method i have to follow, for one case which mentioned above.